# How many people can help treat a disease?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills, disease

Related to some of the other disease-based questions here, I have one that's not covered: how many people can attempt to treat disease on a player using their Heal skill?

My reading of the rules suggests at most one, but I'm not sure.

If so, can others use Aid Another for this individual during the course of the extended rest?

To me, logic suggests that too many people being involved might actually make it harder to treat the patient, i.e. the classic "too many chefs in the kitchen" argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Player's Handbook states under "Cooperation" paragraph (page 179): "Up to four allies can help you, for a maximum bonus of +8".
Since I haven't seen any contradiction to this rule in the paragraph about healing (I don't have Essentials with me, so that might have been errata'd somehow), I would say that only up to 4 people can try to help the healer.

---

ETA: I've got hold of the Rules Compendium: it confirms the max four creature can help a skill check, but also adds that DM can limit this number, even up to zero, in special cases (e.g. picking a lock).

Comment: Also keep in mind that only one pass or fail heal check for the disease being cured, staying the same, or getting worse can be made at the end of each extended rest. Also players shouldn't game the system by taking multiple extended rests.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith There's a specific rules that prohibit taking another extended rest before 18 hours from the last. At least from this angle the system cannot be tricked.

Comment: I felt the need to mention it becuase in-game time is infinitely mutable and you could take and extended rest and say, "and we do nothing all day but nap and recall stories of past adventures" and then do another extended rest disease check. Just throwing a tip in for the GM that the best way to make diseases matter is to really force the party to press on in spite of them.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter whether it is one or more people normally for healing / First Aid only one attempt per disease/wound can be made. But then again if your PC will die if not healed and there is no other way, you might bend the rules a little. Nobody wants to see their character die from Troll Rot or Goblin Toe Fungus because the other player rolled really crap :-D

or maybe make an adventure of getting a special salve or something to heal the person :-)